# Java ArrayList inside an object constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I'm trying to create an `ArrayList` whose members all also have an `ArrayList`. The idea  is that I have an `ArrayList` of modules, and then each module should also have it's own `ArrayList` of students but I'm having difficulty creating the constructor for it. This is what I've got so far

```
import java.util.*;

public class Module {

    private String code;
    private ArrayList<Student> students;

    public Module(){
        students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }

    public Module(String newCode,  ArrayList<Student> students){
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the constructor to work but I think it just creates one general `ArrayList`, whereas I want each module to have its own set of students. Any advice on how to approach this would be very appreciated.

---

To load in the Student's `ArrayList` I've been using scanner like so

```
public void loadStudents(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner infile =new Scanner(new InputStreamReader
                               (new FileInputStream(fileName)));

    int num=infile.nextInt();infile.nextLine();
    for (int i=0;i<num;i++) {
        String u=infile.nextLine();
        String s=infile.nextLine();
        String n=infile.nextLine();
        String c=infile.nextLine();

        Student st = new Student(u,s,n,c);
        students.add(st);

    }
    infile.close();    
}
```

But I'm unsure how to to load in an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`.

Comment: I think your code will do what exactly you want. Are you facing any issues with that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're doing it right...I don't exactly see any flaws with your approach unless you were to make that list `static`, which would *not* do what you want.

As it reads now, each instance of `Module` contains a list of `Students`.  The kicker here is to remember to instantiate new instances of a `Module` when you need one, and populate the list appropriately.

Comment: I think the big problem here is populating it then. I'm trying to get it to load an ArrayList of ArrayLists from a text file and I'm not sure how to go about it. I've been using scanner to load in the students, I'll add the code to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work as intended. Since the `ArrayList` students is `non-static`, each instance of `Module` will have its own `ArrayList`. Also, you would like to set the appropriate setters and getters to manage the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

As your problem seems to be loading a List of Lists, specifically how to get a List of Lists from a text file.

The problem here is your textfile format. As it is now, every Student occupies 4 Lines in your file and there is nothing but students in the file.

There are many possible ways to do this, here's one of them:

For your Modules list you could maybe have one line in the beginning of the File telling you how many modules there are and two specific lines at the beginning of each Module that tell you:

1. The code of the Module
2. The number of Students in the Module

Then following would be the students in the usual format. After that the Module-header lines would be repeated.

Example code:

```
public ArrayList<Module> loadModules(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename)));
    int numModules = infile.nextInt();
    infile.nextLine();
    ArrayList<Module> modules = new ArrayList<Module>(numModules);
    infile.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < numModules; i++) {
        String code = infile.nextLine();
        int numStudents = infile.nextInt();
        infile.nextLine();
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>(numStudents);
        for (int j = 0; j < numStudents; j++) {
            String u = infile.nextLine();
            String s = infile.nextLine();
            String n = infile.nextLine();
            String c = infile.nextLine();
            Student st = new Student(u,s,n,c);
            students.add(st);
        }
        Module md = new Module(code, students);
        modules.add(md);
    }
    infile.close();
    return modules;
}
```

Example textfile to load:

```
2
module1
4
student1u
student1s
student1n
student1c
student2u
student2s
student2n
student2c
student3u
student3s
student3n
student3c
student4u
student4s
student4n
student4c
module2
1
student1u
student1s
student1n
student1c
```

Hope I could help,
//265

EDIT: Corrected fileName Reference error in Line 2

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm after but I'm getting this error when I try to compile : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 fileName cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @LukaszMedza Oh pardon me, I wrote fileName once with camelCase and oce without it. Let me correct that ^^